# Menu in table vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

So, I am working with element plus table, and I want to combine the element plus table and element plus menu i.e.
[image]

I want this kind of drop down menu in my table headers.

```
<el-menu
    :default-active="activeIndex"
    class="el-menu-demo"
    mode="horizontal"
    @select="handleSelect"
  >
    <el-sub-menu index="1">
      <template #title>Workspace</template>
      <el-menu-item index="2-1">item one</el-menu-item>
      <el-menu-item index="2-2">item two</el-menu-item>
      <el-menu-item index="2-3">item three</el-menu-item>
      <el-sub-menu index="2-4">
        <template #title>item four</template>
        <el-menu-item index="2-4-1">item one</el-menu-item>
        <el-menu-item index="2-4-2">item two</el-menu-item>
        <el-menu-item index="2-4-3">item three</el-menu-item>
      </el-sub-menu>
    </el-sub-menu>
  </el-menu>
```

My table is

```
<el-table :data="filtered"  border style="width: 100%" height="500" @selection-change="handleSelectionChange" @header-click="contextmenu">
  <el-table-column type="selection" width="55"/>
  <el-table-column  fixed align="center" v-for="col in columns" :prop="col.field" :label="col.field" :key="col.field"/>
```

[image]

But I am facing a hard time in combining these two tags.
I found out that element plus table has an event  `@header-click=""` that stores the header values etc, but I don't know how I can use that to call the menu tag of element plus.

I am new to vue so any suggestions are appreciated.

**ANSWER**
@IVOGELOV is correct. Here is my final code, I have made a couple of changes since slot-scope is now deprecated.

```
<el-table :data="filtered"  border style="width: 100%" height="500" @selection-change="handleSelectionChange" @header-click="contextmenu" >
  <el-table-column type="selection" width="55"/>
  <el-table-column  fixed align="center"  v-for="col in columns" :prop="col.field" :label="col.field" :key="col.field">
  <template #header >
        <el-menu
          :default-active="activeIndex"
          class="el-menu-demo"
          mode="horizontal"
          @select="handleSelect">
          <el-sub-menu index="1">
            <template #title>{{col.field}}</template>
            <el-menu-item index="2-1">Source</el-menu-item>
            <el-menu-item index="2-2">Target</el-menu-item>
            </el-sub-menu>
        </el-menu>
      </template>  
      </el-table-column>
      <el-table>
```

Comment: what does "call the menu tag" mean? you call functions, not some abstract concepts

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `header` slot in columns or the `render-header` function as explained in [this Chinese article](https://blog.actorsfit.com/a?ID=01000-3a4e048b-3a88-4f12-9b99-17a3d783809d) or [this Github issue](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/issues/4909).

```html
<template>
  <el-table :data="tableData"style="width: 100%">
    <el-table-column prop="name">
      <template slot="header" slot-scope="scope">
        <el-menu
          :default-active="activeIndex"
          class="el-menu-demo"
          mode="horizontal"
          @select="handleSelect"
        >
          <el-sub-menu index="1">
            <template #title>Workspace</template>
            <el-menu-item index="2-1">item one</el-menu-item>
            <el-menu-item index="2-2">item two</el-menu-item>
            <el-menu-item index="2-3">item three</el-menu-item>
            <el-sub-menu index="2-4">
              <template #title>item four</template>
              <el-menu-item index="2-4-1">item one</el-menu-item>
              <el-menu-item index="2-4-2">item two</el-menu-item>
              <el-menu-item index="2-4-3">item three</el-menu-item>
            </el-sub-menu>
          </el-sub-menu>
        </el-menu>
      </template>
    </el-table-column>
  </el-table>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
I have added my final code in the question as slot-scope is now deprecated so that other can get a working version of your answer.
Thank you showing me how to do this.